# Does JWS load JARs inside JAR for applets?

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start

I'm maintaining a Java applet launched via `Java Web Start` but I know little about this technology (we are in the process of moving away from applets but we need some maintenance on it). This applet depends on some external JAR files (batik, etc.).

We use `gradle` as the build system. We build a normal JAR and a fat JAR (with the `com.github.johnrengelman.shadow` plugin) as follows:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
    }
  }
}
repositories {
  flatDir {
    dirs 'lib'
  }
}
dependencies {
  compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.0',
    'jargs:jargs:1.0',
    'org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svggen:1.7',
    'org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-dom:1.7',
    'org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-awt-util:1.7',
    'org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:1.7',
    'org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-xml:1.7',
    'xerces:xercesImpl:2.8.0'
}
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes  'Application-Name': project.name,
                'Permissions': 'all-permissions',
                'Implementation-Title': project.name,
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'Foo',
                'Class-Path': configurations.compile.files.collect{ "lib/${it.name}" }.join(' ')
  }
  baseName project.name
  // include dependencies into lib dir in produced jar
  into('lib') {
    from configurations.runtime
  }
  from "README.md"
}
shadowJar {
  baseName project.name
}
```

`gradle` includes the JAR files in `lib/` folder inside the main JAR and they are added to the `Class-Path` in `MANIFEST.MF`.

The applet works on client computers *with the normal JAR* but I don't fully understand why.

Somehow, the JAR files are loaded when `Java Web Start` launches the applet. They are not mentioned in the JNLP file (no `<resource>`) and there is no class loader (we don't use `JarRsrcLoader` or similar) so I guess it's because they are in `Class-Path` but I am not sure and I haven't been able to produce a MWE. In fact all the information that I have found states the opposite (at least for applications as opposed to applets).

Does anybody know if it's the case or a simple explanation/tutorial ?

Comment: Does it use Eclipse's `JarRsrcLoader` or something like that?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have updated the question.

Comment: The JNLP FAQ states that the Class-Path is not used. So if your Embedded lib/ jars are used this is either done by the application with its own classloader or a not documented feature. Did you check Webserver access log and java console in trace mode what files it actually downloads? Maybe the jnlp file was dynamically generated with more resources?

Comment: @eckes Thanks for your comment (I was referring to the same fact in the JNLP configuration). The JNLP is hand-written and has no more resources. I haven't found any class-loader in the source.

Comment: I have removed all mentions of ShadowJar and all manipulations of `Class-Path` and it still works. Maybe I'm missing something about Java compilation.

Comment: OK, I think I understand. In fact it did not work for the normal AR: the functionality that depends on the external JARs (batik, etc.) is rarely used; the applet starts but when I try this functionality, it fails; the fat JAR version works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was wrong. In fact the JAR files are not loaded: when one tries to access the functionality that needs batik, it fails. This confirms my readings and @eckes and @zakki comments.

I also discovered that I can simplify our `build.gradle` file.